# Installing TurboGears on windows 7

Tags: python, easy-install, turbogears

I tried installing TurboGears 1.0 on Windows 7 using tgsetup.py. and got following error

```
error: Couldn't find a setup script in c:\users\sandre~1\appdata\local\temp\
easy_install-jimbkt\Cheetah-2.4.0.linux-i686.tar.gz
```

When looking into this folder I see easy_install-jimbkt folder appearing and disappearing right away. Is this something Windows 7 does? Anybody know a walkaround for it? I can't use newer version of TG (which actually installs fine) because I have to support project written with TG 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's trying to install the Linux binaries of Cheetah, which definitely won't work on Windows. To get that piece of the puzzle to run in Windows, you can download and install the source version with the following command (I'll assume you already have Python and setuptools installed and working):

```
easy_install install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/C/Cheetah/Cheetah-2.4.0.tar.gz#md5=873f5440676355512f176fc4ac01011e
```

I dunno about the TurboGears 1.0 stuff, though... However, instructions for Windows installation are available [here](http://docs.turbogears.org/1.0/InstallWindows) (but you probably knew that already).

Comment: That was not an answer for me however you gave an idea to go to cheetah homepage and download cheetah binaries for windows. Have no idea why I haven't though about it before